# How to apply a modification to a variable until it doesnt change anymore?

Tags: php, symfony, url

I'm setting up a URL canonicalizer and I need to apply a modification to a variable until it doesn't change anymore.

I already have a working solution, but with flaws. I need to compute the n+1 step twice.
I chose the "do-while" syntax as I need to go in the loop at least once.

```php
do {
    $url = rawurldecode($url);
} while ($url !== rawurldecode($url));
```

I'd like not to calculate the n+1 twice. I've tried using a two variables but I can't get something clean working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do {
    $prevUrl = $url;
    $url = rawurldecode($url);
} while ($url !== $prevUrl);
```

Comment: This is more like a comment, Kindly elaborate your answer